# Is there a way to control which resources/actions a role can define in a new policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I need to make an administrator role where only access to a few resources is blocked. This seems straightforward. I can create a role with 2 policies, one AWS managed `AdministratorAccess` and a deny policy for the relevant resources.

```yaml
ManagedPolicyArns:
  - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
Policies:
  - PolicyName: DenyAccess
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Deny
          Action:
            - '*'
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket
            - ...
```

However, because the role now has full `IAM` access, it seems it can easily by-pass the deny policy. To do this it can create a new policy with full access and assign this policy to a lambda. This lambda then has full access to the resources which are denied to the original role.

Is there a way to control which resources/actions a role can define in a new policy?

I have tried using permission boundaries, as suggested in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491741/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-what-actions-can-be-added-on-an-iam-policy-by-an-iam), but it didn't work.

```yaml
- PolicyName: BoundaryPolicy
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: 'iam:*'
        Resource: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AcountId}:role/*
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
            iam:PermissionsBoundary: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AcountId}:policy/DenyPolicy
```

Comment: Why not deny iam actions as well?

Comment: The role needs to have access to IAM actions. It needs to be able, for example, to create a lambda that has permissions to S3 buckets. That is, S3 buckets the role itself also has access to.

Comment: you can either use organizations and apply an SCP to deny or use Permission boundaries so that the user can't escalate their access more than what has been provided.

Comment: So I tried with the permission boundary as described at the end of the question. However, I was still able to assume te new management role and create a policy with a statement that was denied on the role itself. What did I do wrong in the boundary?